# How to apply a t-test for product failure?

Tags: t-test, survival, failure-rate

**Background**: I'm trying to determine if there is a difference in the rate of failure between two populations. Population 1 is an engine run on one type of fuel.  Population 2 is the same engine run on a different type of fuel.

I have 1000 engines in my first group along with the list of when they failed [5,8,10...]
I have 100 engines in the second group [6,12...]

If everything failed I could test if the means were different with a 2 sample unpaired t test, however since most of the engines never failed, I'm not sure how to easily test whether the two populations really the same.

Comment: Since it is unlikely the engine failure times is a normal distribution and many engineers are still running.  I would not recommend the t-test.  I would recommend a ranked sum test such as the Wilcoxon test.  I suggest a Google search on a survival tests.

Comment: @Dave2e the t-test does not require that the distribution of the sample is normally distributed. Even so, performing a t-test on the log transformed performance times to reduce the influence of long-surviving components could avail two times the power of a rank-based test.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a classic situation for survival analysis, which by design takes into account cases for which there has been no failure by the end of the study.

If you only have 2 groups, no predictors other than the type of fuel, and you don't consider any engines that might have been repaired and put back into service, then showing [Kaplan-Meier estimates](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kaplan%E2%80%93Meier_estimator) of survival over time for each group and using a [log-rank test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logrank_test) to compare the 2 groups would be a standard approach. Tools are provided by standard statistical software, for example the [`survival` package](https://cran.r-project.org/package=survival) in R.

Comment: +1 Echoing that the `survival` also allows for parametric survival regression with censored data, such as an exponential or Weibull distributions which would allow for predictions and post-hoc estimates of mean survival time and perhaps greater power.

Comment: Do you have a recommendation for packages in python?

Comment: @JonathanHay see the [`lifelines`](https://github.com/CamDavidsonPilon/lifelines/blob/master/docs/Survival%20analysis%20with%20lifelines.rst) package. The link is to an explanation of how to use it, starting with Kaplan-Meier and log-rank, then going on to parametric models.